# What does Robin want?

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

In Arkham Knight's DLC "A Matter of Family", Robin is often trying to tell Bat-girl something, but always loses his nerve. By the end of the mini-story, Robin didn't get to say what he wants to say, at least not in my game. What did Robin want to say to Bat-girl?

Comment: I haven't played it yet, hasn't come out on PC yet, but if the "true" ending is any indication, if he appears nervous, it might be related.

Comment: Ive put up my reasoning, as it iwas pretty obvious for me, as soon as I read your question. I hope this does answer your query, but regardless, I think this relys too much on speculation.

Comment: Voting to leave open as per http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7696/should-lore-questions-as-an-entire-category-be-banned and http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7673/when-is-it-appropriate-to-close-a-lore-question-as-not-addressed-directly-throu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not played the Batgirl DLC, myself. I think it is also difficult to speculate what a fictional character *wanted* to say, without the developers themselves telling us their intentions. But I speculate he was trying to (tell her he likes her/ how he feels/ ask her out), and here is why:

**The Batgirl DLC is set before the main game.** This is pretty obvious; Barbara Gordon was Batgirl, before she became Oracle.

> Before Arkham City, the Joker shot her, through the spine. This paralyzed her from the waist down, forcing her into retirement.

**In Batman: Arkham Knight, Robin has a thing for Oracle.** It was my impression that they were dating.

> At the very least, Batman mentions that he won't tell Robin about Oracle, when she is kidnapped and apparently commits suicide, due to "how he feels about her".

Comment: I like the answer but it would be a little bit more authoritative if it came from somebody who had actually played the DLC